# AVERAGEIF/AVERAGEIFS with TODAY() and other dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to average scores based on if they happened in less than 1 year ago 1-2 years ago and 2-3 years ago.

For the less than a year ago I have this **that is working**

`=AVERAGEIF(C2:C200,">" & TODAY()-365,D2:D200)`

**But** for more than 365 days but less than 730 days I have tried this (among other things):

`=AVERAGEIFS(D2:D20,C2:C20, ">" & TODAY()-365,C2:C20, "<" & TODAY() -730)`

but no matter what I try I get a #DIV/0! error or the wrong average.

Comment: Flip your `>` and `<` both are reversed.

Comment: Also note that there are better ways than hard-coding `365` and `730` that handle leap years, for example.

Comment: Somehow I still get a #DIV/0! when they are flipped

Comment: If there are better ways to code this I would love to know! For my puposes it just needs to happen automatically when new information is added

Comment: Are you sure you want to change your criteria ranges? In your `AVERAGEIF()` you are using `E2:E20`. You have changed that to `C2:C20` in your `AVERAGEIFS()`.

Comment: I thought that in ```AVERAGEIF()``` it's ```range, criteria, [average_range]``` and for ```AVERAGEIFS``` it's ```average_rage, criteria_range, criteria, criteria_range_2, criteria_2```?

Comment: You went from column E as criteria range in the first formula, to col C as criteria range in the second formula. If you're getting a DIV/0 with the correct columns and the signs flipped per Scott's comment, then you don't have any matching data.

Comment: Oh right, I realized I copied the old piece of code rather than the newer one which is ```=AVERAGEIF(C2:C200,">" & TODAY()-365,D2:D200)```
E was my old 'days column'
Column C is my 'dates' and D is 'scores'
I fixed it in my original post

Comment: I think the #DIV/0! comes about if you don't have any matches in your range

Comment: It's weird though because I for sure have data matching my criteria in the range

Answer (score 1):

Should work if you replace 20 with 200

```
=AVERAGEIFS(D2:D200,C2:C200,"<" & TODAY()-365,C2:C200,">" & TODAY()-730)
```